# Android and iOS web app wrapped in a native one

Tags: android, ios, html

Did anyone ever think of developing an iOS and Android app in HTML5 but wrapped in a native app, using the Webkit control?

Would that make it to the App Store?

I don't want to invest time learning iOS, then redevelop for Android. HTML5 + some boiler plate initialization code would make a nice solution and minimize platform dependency.

Ideas?

Comment: I did a bit of research and found web frameworks, nothing that wraps into native apps, but OK I found now, phonegap seems to do exactly that, anyone happy with it?

Comment: Generally if you just want an app on as many platforms as possible, as quickly as possible and don't care about their quality then solutions such as phonegap will please you. However, if you really care about the quality of the app and your users experience when using it, you should write native apps.

Comment: You will need to spend time learning both platforms from a UI design standpoint at the very least either way. Users of both Android and iOS are very critical of apps that do not follow platform conventions, or that reuse non-native conventions from another platform. If you simply wrap a generic web UI in a native app, expect overwhelmingly negative user reviews.

Answer (score 1):

you can checkout,

http://www.appcelerator.com

and

http://www.phonegap.com

what both does is, it wraps HTML5 within native app.
There are many applications build by both and approved in AppStore.

check sites, to check what apps are in example , that are approved